# How to implement a filter on a query in Apollo?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm attempting to filter a query by a specific field. I can achieve this in Apollo explorer in dev tools but I can't seem to translate this into code.

The following works in Apollo explorer:

```
query ListUsersByType($filter: TableUsersFilterInput) {
  listUsers(filter: $filter) {
    items {
      email
      id
      type
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "filter": {
    "type": {
      "eq": "ADMIN"
    }
  }
}
```

I am unsure how this translates to the code using the useQuery hook however.

When I try the following it doesn't filter the list at all, it just fetches all of them regardless of type:

```
const ListUsersByType = gql`
  query ListUsersByType($type: TableUsersFilterInput) {
    listUsers(filter: $type) {
      items {
        email
        id
        type
      }
    }
  }
`
```

```
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(ListUsersByType, {
    variables: {
      filter: {
        type: {
          eq: 'ADMIN',
        },
      },
    },
  })
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your names are not correct

Here you say `filter will use the variable type`

```js
const ListUsersByType = gql`
  query ListUsersByType($type: TableUsersFilterInput) {
    listUsers(filter: $type) {
      items {
        email
        id
        type
      }
    }
  }
`
```

And here you pass `filter`

```js
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(ListUsersByType, {
    variables: {
      filter: {
        type: {
          eq: 'ADMIN',
        },
      },
    },
  })
```

You can

**First solution**

replace `$type` by `$filter`

```js
const ListUsersByType = gql`
  query ListUsersByType($filter: TableUsersFilterInput) {
    listUsers(filter: $filter) {
      items {
        email
        id
        type
      }
    }
  }
`
```

**Second solution**

rename the variable `filter` to `type`

```js
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(ListUsersByType, {
    variables: {
      type: {
        type: {
          eq: 'ADMIN',
        },
      },
    },
  })
```

**My opinion**

I let you choose but the first option seems the best